# mysql case multiple variables

Tags: mysql, if-statement, case

I need to instruct the query (at the bottom) to return the QUARTER value converted into a named result based on the following: 03 = 1st, 06 = 2nd, 09 = 3rd, and 12 = 4th.  So, what I am looking for when running the query is for the "QUARTER" Column to return "1st" in place of "03".  Thank you...

RESULTS OF QUERY

```
Year    Quarter  Quarterly_yield
2012      03         8.41
2012      06         -0.71
2012      09         0.03
2012      12         3.43
```

THE QUERY

```
select    RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2) Quarter,
          LEFT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 4) Year,
          ROUND(A.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Quarterly_yield
from      dr_rent_carteras_trimestres A

Order by A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE asc
```

*Note: The first Field titled "F_ANOTRIMESTRE" contains a YEARQUARTER value, so I am using RIGHT to select only the Quarter Value.

Comment: Are you outputting this on a website?  You could use a while statement and keep track of each pass.

Comment: Do you mean you want to sort it by `Quarter`?

Comment: I figured it out.  I needed to use either CASE or IF statement.  Following is what I did:  IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2)=03,'Enero a Marzo',
          IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2)=06,'Abril a Junio',
          IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2)=09,'Julio a Septiembre',
          IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2)=12,'Octubre a Diciembre',